# Tomcat 8.0.30 Windows Service not running with Log4j2 Confguration

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, log4j2, tomcat8

i sit here for 2 days with a serious problem. i have to configure Tomcat 8.0.30 via a Windows Service to run with Log4j2 but i always just receive the error message in the log:

```
2016-02-07 19:49:19 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

That is very strange for me as i can start Tomcat 8.0 via "Catalina.bat start" without any problem with the same libraries and classpath settings.

Here are my settings in the WindowsService:

Tab "Java" - 
Java Options:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat8030test
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat8030test
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Tomcat8030test\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat8030test\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j2.xml
-Djava.class.path=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-jul-2.5.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-jcl-2.5.jar;C:\tomcat8\lib\log4j2.xml;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-core-2.5.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-api-2.5.jar;C:\tomcat8\lib\log4j2.xml;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\tomcat-juli-adapters.jar"
```

Tab "startup" 
Class
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
Java Classpath:
C:\Tomcat8030test\bin\bootstrap.jar

Working Path:
C:\Tomcat8030test

Beside that:
Here are my Filesystem settings

```
%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar (i checked the jar, the missing file is there and has Log4j2 version 2.5). 

\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar
\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar
\lib\log4j-1.2-api-2.5.jar
\lib\log4j2.xml
\lib\log4j-api-2.5.jar
\lib\log4j-core-2.5.jar
\lib\log4j-jcl-2.5.jar
lib\log4j-jul-2.5.jar
\lib\log4j-web-2.5.jar
```

As i explained the startup via the catalina.bat works wonderful. 
Here are the settings:

```
rem tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" goto juliClasspathHome
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-jul-2.5.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-jcl-2.5.jar;C:\tomcat8\lib\log4j2.xml;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-core-2.5.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\log4j-api-2.5.jar;C:\tomcat8\lib\log4j2.xml;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\lib\tomcat-juli-adapters.jar"
goto juliClasspathDone
:juliClasspathHome
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
:juliClasspathDone

rem if not "%LOGGING_CONFIG%" == "" goto noJuliConfig
rem set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Dnop
rem if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" goto noJuliConfig
set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\tomcat8\lib\log4j2.xml"
rem set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
rem :noJuliConfig
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%"

if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" goto noJuliManager
rem set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
....
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS%  -Dlog4j.configurationFile="C:\tomcat8\lib\log4j2.xml" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION% '
```

The Tomcat-Juli.jar is of Version 2.5 and does contain this missing class.

Please help.